# Who owns the Elder Wand in "Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them"?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In *Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them*, when Tina disarms Graves,

> (Grindelwald)

does she then become the owner of the Elder Wand?

Comment: @Valorum Tina didn't disarm him. She just accio-ed fallen wand..

Comment: @ILoveYou - Oh yeah. That's right. He'd dropped it; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149218/why-does-newt-scamander-use-accio-instead-of-expelliarmus-to-get-the-bad-guys-w/149291#149291

Comment: My instinct is that you have to be using the wand at the time you're disarmed/defeated. Also, it gravitates toward the more powerful wizard.

Comment: The Elder Wand, being made with Thestral Tail Hair, can only be won by a Witch or Wizard capable of facing Death. Even if Tina disarmed him, if she isn't capable of facing Death and is not a Master of Death, she still wouldn't gain the allegiance of the wand, which would remain with <spoiler>.

Comment: @Valorum You don't have to even possess the wand to lose its allegiance. Harry won it from Draco and Draco didn't even know he had the allegiance of the Elder Wand, let alone have it with him in the manor.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo `The Elder Wand, being made with Thestral Tail Hair, can only be won by a Witch or Wizard capable of facing Death. Even if Tina disarmed him, if she isn't capable of facing Death and is not a Master of Death, she still wouldn't gain the allegiance of the wand, which would remain with <spoiler>.` ~> Which kind of theory is that? Do you mean Draco was capable of facing death when he gained allegiance of Elder Wand?

Comment: @SachinStark IF he gained that allegiance. It's never postulated as more than a theory.

Comment: @Weckar Yes, he indeed gained allegiance of Elder Wand. Otherwise, how could Harry gain allegiance of Elder Wand? Harry never even dueled Dumbledore.

Answer (score 5):

## Grindelwald owns, as in physically possesses, the Elder Wand.

In the promotional picture for the next movie in the series, *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, Grindelwald is seen holding the Elder Wand.

[image: Grindelwald]

This doesn’t show whether he’s the *master* of the Elder Wand, but it shows that he *has* the Elder Wand. That he has it is referenced on Pottermore, in one of their pieces giving information on the next movie.

> **Grindelwald has the Elder Wand**
> In this new photo, Grindelwald is seen holding the familiar, textured wand we recognise from the Harry Potter films. From the books, we know that Grindelwald stole the most powerful wand in the wizarding world from the wandmaker Gregorovitch quite early on in his reign of terror. 
> <sub><sup>*[Everything we know about Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald so far](https://www.pottermore.com/news/everything-we-know-about-fantastic-beasts-the-crimes-of-grindelwald-so-far), Pottermore*</sup></sub>

He’s also seen holding it in the second trailer released for Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald, which is referenced in a news release on Pottermore.

> **Grindelwald has the Elder Wand**
>
> [image]
>
> Well, that settles that. The Elder Wand, one of the three Deathly Hallows, is definitely in Grindelwald’s possession during the events of this movie. There is simply no mistaking its recognisable berry-esque carvings that we remember oh-so-well from the Harry Potter films.
>
> As far as we know, the next person to take the wand was Dumbledore after their famous 1945 duel. The Crimes of Grindelwald is set in the 1920s so... blimey, does that mean Grindelwald owns the wand for at least two decades? That doesn’t sound like a fun two decades, if so. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Everything we noticed from the Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald Comic-Con trailer (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/news/everything-we-noticed-from-the-fantastic-beasts-the-crimes-of-grindelwald-comic-con-trailer)*</sup></sub>

So, at the time of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, Grindelwald physically possessed the Elder Wand and seems to be using it as his own, though we don’t know yet if he’s its true master.

### It’s not confirmed yet, but Tina probably isn’t the Elder Wand’s master.

It’s unlikely that Tina would have changed the Elder Wand’s mastery, since she didn’t “win” over Grindelwald. Grindelwald dropped the wand he had been using, and Tina summoned it away. She neither Disarmed him using Expelliarmus, nor did she wrestle the wand from his hand.

> “*With a sense that he’s been holding this one back, he slashes it through the air: out flies a crackling rope of supernatural light that wraps itself around GRAVES like a whip. GRAVES tries to hold it off as it tightens but staggers, struggles and falls to his knees, dropping his wand.*
>
> TINA
>
> *Accio*.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Grindelwald likely would have had mastered the Elder Wand himself before his encounter with Newt and Tina, so if he did, the mastery of the wand would likely be with either him or Newt. To get the Elder Wand, Grindelwald had broken in, Stunned Gregorovitch, and stole the wand - Stunning him would likely count as defeating him.

Comment: How do you know that's Elder Wand? Why can't other wands have same design?

Comment: @Bat The article I linked from Pottermore explicitly says it’s the Elder Wand.

Comment: And, how do you know it's not a publicity stunt of the movie?

Comment: @Bat It would be a rather odd publicity stunt to explicitly state and show Grindelwald has the Elder Wand, when we know from the books this should be true, to reveal in the movie that he doesn’t,

Comment: @Bellatrix - Rowling has said in an interview that the identity of the current owner is a spoiler, so I doubt Grindelwald has it. The articles you linked to are just speculation by the Pottermore team, who really don't know any more than anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually not sure why there is so much debate on this subject. It was quite obvious to me whats happened so far if you understand that JK will very much reuse old plot devices in her work because... it’s easy and very much in line with her writing style:

1. Grindlewald was the master of the Elder Wand in FB1 since he's undefeated upto this point
2. Newt defeats Grindlewald at the end of FB1 (he clearly restrains him with his spell) and is now the master of the wand (remember tina only summoned the wand after newt won so she's irrelevant to the discussion)
3. Newt is the only one actually able to defend against the protego diabolical spell in FB2 (watch closely, it incinerates the Aurors while Newt has no problem deflecting it out of his way) because as master of the Elder Wand the spell wont hurt him. Thesius only deflects the fire because a) he's alongside Newt who’s actually doing the work (unless I'm mistaken they're side by side for most of the scene) or b) because leta's 'love' saves him when he's briefly separated from Newt (we do remember the whole love thing right? why else would leta's death change the fire like that and why would she mention "doing it to save him")

aaaaand thats where we are so far. Newt is pretty obviously the current master based on the above observations and we just have to wait and see what happens next.

The simplest solution would be grindlewald defeating newt in a later movie so hes back in charge of it for the 'Dumbleduel'

However I suspect JK is going to go for a rehash of her 'who's actually the master' plot device from harry potter - ie: Dumbledore will disarm Newt at some point and will be the Elder Wand master (unbeknownst to Grindlewald) so he will have the edge in the 'Dumbleduel' allowing him to beat Grindlewald. This actually makes sence since Dumbledore will use the same strategy to help Harry beat Voldemort decades later (Dude had to learn the strategy from somewhere, why not by using it to take down Grindelwald first).

Comment: Thanks dude! I appreciate a good editor ^_^

Answer (score 0):

### We don't know

Rowling has said in an interview that the identity of the current owner would be a spoiler, so we can probably assume Grindelwald doesn't have it during the events of the first film (him having it was already shown in the books ave thus wouldn't constitute a spoiler).

> **What happened to the Elder wand? Where is it? The elusive Elder wand.**
>
> ***JK Rowling:*** *Where is it right now?*
>
> **Yeah.**
>
> ***JK Rowling:*** *I can't tell you, but you will find out in movie two*
>
> <sub>(Snitchseeker interviews JK Rowling - Fantastic Beasts premiere)</sub>

As shown by the promotional material cited in Bellatrix's answer, Grindelwald likely acquires it at some point during the second movie, but we really don't know who has it before that point.

Comment: The Movie Handbook says that it was returned to him after his escape by "an acolyte"

Comment: @Valorum - that sounds like a really lame twist

Answer (score 0):

The person holding the Elder Wand at the end of the *Crimes of Grindelwald* trailer is holding it in their left hand. Grindelwald appears to always hold it in his right. Also, you’ll notice the carriage is still being pursued by Aurors in the background, bottom left.

Comment: Is there evidence to show that Tina is left-handed, you've not commented on who wields it.